# Is there a router that acts as a VPN to get into the network but also sends traffic out through a VPN?

Tags: vpn, routing

I have several servers that I want to lock down so they're only assessable from inside the network so I need a router that allows me to VPN in. On top of that I want certain ports(22,8022) from my servers location to go through another VPN. Is this possible, what should I be looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Most modern firewall appliances do a decent job as a VPN concentrator - routing traffic through various VPN tunnels - and a good SSL VPN appliance is worth looking into for user access into your secure network: it offers security features (such as checking the AV definitions on the user's PC to see if it's up to date) and ease of deployment to the user's desktop (usually a java app launched by the browser) that are not always available with traditional VPN solutions.